# R Highcharter: On x-axis, Date is not showing correctly when dataframe has only one result

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm building a shiny app that displays actual vs planned expenditure on a monthly basis. I've created controls that allow the user to select a specific project. But in some projects, there are only planned expenditure for a single month is there. For those projects, the Date is not coming properly on the X-Axis.

[image: Planned vs Actual Expenditure]

He is the code that I've written:

```
renderHighchart({
  highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = planned_vs_actual()$documentDate, title = list(text = "<b>Date</b>"), type = "datetime") %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Planned Expenditure",
                data = planned_vs_actual()$PlannedExpenditure) %>%
  hc_add_series(name="Actual Expenditure",
                data = planned_vs_actual()$ActualExpenditure) %>%
  hc_tooltip(borderWidth = 1.5,
             pointFormat = paste('<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>')) %>%
    hc_legend(enabled = TRUE) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Planned vs Actual Expenditure (In Crores)") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = dataPeriod) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "<b>Amount <br>(In Crores)</br></b>"))%>%
    hc_add_theme(custom_theme)
})
```

Comment: Hi. Could you list all the packages you are using so I can run your code in RStudio by copy/paste?

Comment: `libraries <- 
  c("data.table", "plyr", 
    "readxl", "ggplot2", "lubridate", "dplyr", 
    "tidyverse","janitor","odbc","DBI","dbplyr",
    "lubridate","tidylog","stringi","flexdashboard",
    "highcharter","plotly","viridis","countrycode",
    "rjson","crosstalk","DT","openxlsx","shiny","reshape2")

# Install CRAN libraries (if not already installed)
.inst <- libraries %in% installed.packages()
if(length(libraries[!.inst]) > 0) install.packages(libraries[!.inst])

#Load Libraries
lapply(libraries, require, character.only = TRUE)`

Comment: It might sound stupid, but could you just list it manually? I am not R developer - I am JavaScript developer still learning R. I'll help you with Highcharts, but I just need to run your code first.

Comment: @raf18seb Here are the libraries used - "data.table", "plyr", "readxl", "ggplot2", "lubridate", "dplyr", "tidyverse","janitor","odbc","DBI","dbplyr", "lubridate","tidylog","stringi","flexdashboard", "highcharter","plotly","viridis","countrycode", "rjson","crosstalk","DT","openxlsx","shiny","reshape2". Using the above code would have helped you in installing them in case they were not installed.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution on this link: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/395

Just need to make this change:

```
hc_xAxis(categories = as.list(planned_vs_actual()$documentDate), title = list(text = "<b>Date</b>"), type = "datetime")
```

Put the **date** in `as.list()` function to show it properly on x-axis.